# Updating yaw with msg_request_data_stream and MavlinkObserver

Tags: dronekit, dronekit-android

I am working on a project in which I am controlling a quadcopter with an android phone. I have noticed that the using the `DroneListener` to listen for `ATTITUDE_UPDATED` messages is not updating the yaw nearly as fast enough as I need it to. I would like to get the quadcopter’s yaw updated frequently, in (more or less) real time, such as how the Mission Planner application does when you plug your quadcopter in via usb.

I have tried using `msg_request_data_stream` (that is essentially what Mission Planner uses, but in C#) to request various data streams from the drone, but it has not worked. My assumption is that such the response to this request (i.e., the stream) would be received by any registered MavlinkObservers, however the custom `MavlinkObserver` that I have added to my drone has not had its `onMavlinkMessageReceived(…)` method called a single time. It has not even received heartbeat messages, which should (based on my understanding) be coming reqularly and frequently.

Is there any help that you could offer? Is there any better way to get the quadcopter’s yaw than waiting for the DroneListener to be notified of events? I know that it should be possible with Mavlink (`MissionPlanner` does it), but I haven’t been having any success with Mavlink messages or with a `MavlinkObserver`.

Here is my code for requesting a data stream:

```
msg_request_data_stream message = new msg_request_data_stream();

//not sure how doubles cast to byte, so I cast it to an int first (the value is
//always going to be an int anyway, getValue just returns doubles for parameters by default)
message.target_system = (byte)((int)params.getParameter("SYSID_THISMAV").getValue());

message.req_message_rate = (short)1;
message.req_stream_id = (byte)0;
message.start_stop = (byte)1;

//wrap the message and send it!
ExperimentalApi.sendMavlinkMessage(this, new MavlinkMessageWrapper(message));
```